# Android 4.0 MapView with ActionBar

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Can somebody give me a good example on how to use a MapView with the ActionBar in Android 4.0 ICS?
Isn't there something like a MapFragment or so?
I want my app to have view control in the actionbar (dropdownlist for navigation) and one of the fragments has to be a map

Comment: [Latest Android Developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/12/new-google-maps-android-api-now-part-of.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps API for Android v2 has MapFragment. It's documented in developers.google.com.